# External hard drive suddenly unable to mount

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, external-disk, mount, hdd

In Disk Utility, where the name of my HDD's physical volume should appear, it now instead says "--" and is greyed out. Additionally, though the relevant "mount" button is clickable, it has no effect. And as one might expect, nothing shows up on the Desktop or in the Finder sidebar either.

After trying a whole load of different things – articles, video tutorials, scouring through forum posts – and putting in many hours of (almost*) fruitless effort, I'm seeking some inspiration and ideas that somebody out there might have...

I've had no luck in trying various combinations of:

- `diskutil mount /dev/disk2` (or `disk2s2`)
- `diskutil mountDisk /dev/disk2` (or `disk2s2`)
- `diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk2` (or `disk2s2`)
- `diskutil eject /dev/disk2` (or `disk2s2`)

I also tried the following as per [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QMvYHgQOEvA):

- `sudo mkdir /Volumes/usb`
- `sudo mount -t hfs /dev/disk2 /Volumes/usb/`
- `sudo mount -t hfs /dev/disk2s2 /Volumes/usb/`

I did encounter other potentially useful Terminal commands in [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/305071/force-mounting-an-external-disk-that-is-not-recognized) (e.g. the inclusion of `force`), but admittedly I'm not confident enough to be sure I can use them safely in my scenario.

To add some background, if it helps, I suspect the issue could be to do with a "Disk Not Ejected Properly" event.

In the couple of days prior to encountering the problem, I'd been using the device in a USB hub which had been causing the ejection of connected devices; for example, immediately upon plugging in anything additional. In another instance, there was a spontaneous "improper" ejection of all devices while all ports were occupied. I can't pinpoint the exact causal scenario, but the problem seems likely to have arisen from one of these such episodes.

I've seen posts that mention that a disk can be kind of "held hostage" by `fsck` after such an event, but running `ps aux | grep fsck` came up with nothing. Could there be another process at play here?

Nothing in Activity Monitor seems suspicious, but then again, I'm not exactly sure what I should look for.

Any ideas?

***PS:** One bit of good news is that I've found there's definitely something to work with...

Interestingly, when I took a cursory glance at the HDD in [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk), an amount of used capacity (appearing to be roughly accurate) was listed with the "missing" volume, suggesting that all is perhaps not lost. Further to this, I then ran a partial "Deep Scan" in a free demo of [Data Rescue 6](https://www.prosofteng.com/mac-data-recovery/), and the files and folders – at least in the portion I scanned – are indeed still there... But what could be preventing this HDD from mounting?

For the record, the HDD in question uses a GUID Partition Map and the file system format is Mac OS Extended (Journaled). It is less than a year old and has never shown any previous signs of malfunction or potential failure in my time of using it.

Comment: Have you tried verifying or repairing the volume? - `sudo diskutil verifyVolume /dev/disk2`

Comment: Hi @Mr R. I just tried `diskutil verifyDisk /dev/disk2` which looked fine, however `diskutil verifyVolume /dev/disk2s2` outputted a number of errors. The first three lines were as normal, but then followed: `Invalid B-tree node size`, `The volume   could not be verified completely`, `File system check exit code is 8`, `Error: -69845: File system verify or repair failed` and `Underlying error: 8: Exec format error`. Both were tried with and without `sudo`.  I haven't tried `repairVolume`; is this any different from "First Aid" in Disk Utility?

Comment: Hi @Arturo in the old days we'd have used fsck ... This [article from 2019](https://eclecticlight.co/2019/09/30/should-you-trust-disk-utilitys-first-aid-or-fsck/) suggests fsck -y might do slight more than repair.

Comment: The other thing to note is most of the articles say single user mode, or via recovery mode - so the disk isn't in-use at time of repair.

Comment: Thanks @Mr R – that article gives me a few ideas. At some point I'll most probably give `fsck -y` a try, but my precautionary instinct – though I'm not exactly sure how reasonable it is – is to first create a backup "disk image". Re: the suggestion of restarting in Recovery Mode to ensure the volume is unmounted, would this make a difference when the volume in question _is_ unmounted (and very much _unmountable_)?