# Why is my 2015 MBP only recognizing a 2TB SSD upgrade, and not 4TB of the same type?

Tags: ssd, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade the internal SSD to a 4TB PCIe 3.0 x4 drive, on my 2015 MacBook Pro. I've already done this with a 2TB PCIe 3.0 drive and it worked fine. But in this case, the drive is not recognized, despite using the same kind of bus.

How do I get it working?

The one that has worked before was a [Samsung 970 EVO Plus 2TB NVMe M.2 SSD](https://a.co/d/gu50K9U).

The one I am trying to use is a [Crucial P3 4TB NVMe M.2 SSD](https://a.co/d/dX43JeQ) I got on Prime Day.

According to [this beetstech article](https://hyp.is/RAgPbCM-Ee6udkMCvDM9GQ/beetstech.com/blog/apple-proprietary-ssd-ultimate-guide-to-specs-and-upgrades), the 2015 Mac SSDs used a PCIe 3.0 x4 interface.

The adapter I used for both is a [Micro Connectors MacBook M.2 NVME Upgrade Adapter Card](https://www.microcenter.com/product/656338/micro-connectors-macbook-m2-nvme-upgrade-adapter-card-80mm?rd=1).

It's even recognized over USB using a [gen 2x1 adapter](https://www.microcenter.com/support/632927/micro-connectors-m2-nvme-ssd-to-usb-32-gen-2x1-10gbps-type-a-male-adapter-(nvme-31usba)), and I've gone so far as to complete a full OSX install and migration that way; but the drive still won't be recognized after installing the OS then installing the drive internally.

It's missing when pulling up Disk Utility on a bootable Monterey install drive. `mount` appears to be leaving a disk unmounted (not sure it's mine), but when trying to mount that one I get the error, "`mount: disk1s1: invalid special file or file system`," even when formatted. Following the instructions on [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/305389/378042) didn't help.

I'd love to be able to use it on this machine that's still running strong, so the original installation can use a full 2TB instead of the original 1TB while still leaving room for a 2TB Bootcamp installation, currently running Windows 11.

I have a WD_BLACK 4TB SN850X Gen4 PCIe, M.2 2280 drive coming in a couple weeks that I could try on it, but it's pretty overkill for this computer.